# Unable to Download Kindle Books/Dropbox files

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have a Samsung Note II running Android 4.4.2. I recently rooted it, and after rooting I am unable to download content for certain apps, for example Kindle books or dropbox files.

Some other apps seem to work fine.

Thinking this is a file permissions issue, I downloaded an app called "Fix Me Storage" which seems to run successfully, but I'm still running into this issue. I also tried the NextApp SDFix tool and it said no action was required.

I have enough storage on the device but am still unable to do this.

**Sample Scenarios:**

1. Kindle: When I try to download a book on a kindle, I get this error:

> "Unable to Download": A network connection is required to download
>   your Kindle title. Please connect to a network and try again.

This happens on Wifi and 4G, and even after uninstalling, rebooting and reinstalling the app.

2. Dropbox: When I try to open a pdf file with a viewer on the device (Drive PDF Viewer, or ezPDF), I get this error:

> Storage full or unavailable.

However, I have ample room, both on the phone and the plugged in SD Card.

Comment: It might help if you could include some more details: Where are you trying to download to? With Kitkat, first thing coming to my mind are the SD card restrictions it introduced (and which can be fixed using e.g. [SDFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.sdfix)).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try SDFix. I'm just trying to download books (on the Kindle), or open PDF Files.